# Как принято распределять сущности если их много?

Tags: java, spring, mvc

К примеру есть много сущностей. Есть главный класс BaseEntity в пакете model. 
И к примеру от него наследуются растения, овощи, фрукты. И вот тут загвоздка. Стоит ли создать отдельный подпакет в model, plants в нем класс TypedEntity extends BaseEntity - для свойств всех растений который наследуется от BaseEntity, ну и классы растений со своими свойствами ?

Или к примеру есть пакет model, а в нем пакет  электронная техника и в этом пакете класс TypedEntity для похожих свойств, от которого унаследуются телевизоры, ноуты и т.д.

Примеры конечно так себе, но интересует сама иерархия. Нормально ли делать такую структуру?

Comment: должно быть так : superclass(пакет) в нем абстрактный класс; dao(пакет) в нем интерфейсы; entity( пакет) в нем классы java extends от superclass; ну как то так; пакеты надо создавать ,если есть необходимость, а вообще надо придерживаться правилам, чтобы самому проще потом было разобраться и другим... главное, чтобы были суперклассы потом интерфейсы потом классы все по разным пакетам.